# Group and sum array of obects using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

How to group an array of objects using object value, and then sum the column values of grouped objects. this is the sample object.

```
let salesData = [
   {
       'phone': 'iPhone',
       'city': 'NewYork',
       '01/09': 200,
       '02/09': '',
       '03/09': 120,
       '04/09': ''

   },
   {
       'phone': 'iPhone',
       'city': 'Los Angels',
       '01/09': 80,
       '02/09': 140,
       '03/09': '',
       '04/09': 15
   },
   {
        'phone': 'Samsung',
        'city': 'New York',
        '01/09': '',
        '02/09': 70,
        '03/09': 10
        '04/09': 20
   }
],
dynamicKeys = ['01/09', '02/09', '03/09'];
```

Here i need to group the data with city and sum the values of dynamicKeys, like this

```
[
   {
     'city': 'New York',
     '01/09': 200,
     '02/09': 70,
     '03/09': 130
   },
   {
     'city': 'Los Angels',
     '01/09': 80,
     '02/09': 140,
     '03/09': ''
 
   }
]
```

this is the code i tried, but its not working

```
let newArr = salesData.reduce((acc, item) => {
   let existItem = acc.find(d => 
      item.city === d.city
   )
   if(existItem){
     dynamicKeys.forEach(d => {
        if(!isNaN(item[d])) existItem[d] += item[d]
     })
   }else{
     acc.push(item);
   }
   return acc
},[])
```

here the grouping seems to be working, but the sum of dynamicKeys is not correct, what is the best way to achieve this using loadsh / plain js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the desired structure using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), we create an object with properties for each city name, then properties for each sales date in dynamic keys.

Once we have built this object, we can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the data as an array:

```js
const salesData = [ { 'phone': 'iPhone', 'city': 'New York', '01/09': 200, '02/09': '', '03/09': 120, '04/09': ''  }, { 'phone': 'iPhone', 'city': 'Los Angeles', '01/09': 80, '02/09': 140, '03/09': '', '04/09': 15 }, { 'phone': 'Samsung', 'city': 'New York', '01/09': '', '02/09': 70, '03/09': 10, '04/09': 20 } ]; 
const dynamicKeys = ['01/09', '02/09', '03/09'];

const result = Object.values(salesData.reduce((acc, salesItem) => { 
    return dynamicKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
       acc[salesItem.city] = acc[salesItem.city] || { city: salesItem.city }; 
       acc[salesItem.city][key] = (+acc[salesItem.city][key] || 0) + (+salesItem[key] || 0);
       return acc;
    }, acc);
}, {}))

console.log('Sales data:', result)
```